# ignore returned value procedure/function VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have several functions and procedures in a VHDL package.
I wanted to ask if there is a way of ignore the out items of these.
I know the open keyword for port maps.
I am using dummy signals assigned to the procedure out. But it might be more efficient way to do this.

¿Is there such a thing for VHDL?
If I set the out signals to open I get the following error:
"Formal e5 of mode out must have an associated actual"

Thanks in advance,
Antonio

EDITED: code

```
procedure reg2ind
 (signal reg : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  signal e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8 : out std_logic;
  signal e9,e10,e11,e12,e13,e14,e15,e16 : out std_logic) is 
begin
  e1 <= reg(0);
  e2 <= reg(1);      
  e3 <= reg(2);
  e4 <= reg(3);
  e5 <= reg(4);
  e6 <= reg(5);
  e7 <= reg(6);
  e8 <= reg(7);
  e9 <= reg(8);
  e10 <= reg(9);
  e11 <= reg(10);
  e12 <= reg(11);
  e13 <= reg(12);
  e14 <= reg(13);
  e15 <= reg(14);
  e16 <= reg(15);
end reg2ind;
```

When I use it:

```
reg2ind(val183,ord_p.err.err_17,ord_p.err.err_18,
ord_p.err.err_19,ord_p.err.err_20,open,open,open,open,open,open,
open,open,open,open, open,open);
```

Comment: Please add some code so that we can see where the error came from

Comment: With so many arguments I'd insist on named association for a start.

Comment: Yes, I have declared several record data type. But I cannot custom all the code I want. I declared this procedure to move a 16-bit register to some data field in my record data type in order to compact more the data

Comment: You try to assign 17 input values to a 16bit vector, maybe that's your mistake. You assign **val138**, **ord_p.err.err_17**, **ord_p.err.err_18**, **ord_p.err.err_19**, **ord_p.err.err_20** (5 bits) and 12 bits for **open**

Comment: @michi.b -  val138 is the positional actual for the input formal reg in the procedure call.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) isn't critical to understanding the analysis error.

See IEEE Std 107-2008, 10.7 Procedure call statement, para 4:

> For each formal parameter of a procedure, a procedure call shall specify exactly one corresponding actual parameter. This actual parameter is specified either explicitly, by an association element (other than the actual **open**) in the association list or, in the absence of such an association element, by a default expression (see 6.5.2).

See 4.2 Subprogram declarations, 4.2.2.3 Signal parameters para 1:

> For a formal parameter of class **signal**, references to the signal, the driver of the signal, or both, are passed into the subprogram call.

and para 6:

> If an actual signal is associated with a signal parameter of any mode, the actual shall be denoted by a static signal name. It is an error if a conversion function or type conversion appears in either the formal part or the actual part of an association element that associates an actual signal with a formal signal parameter.

Also see 14.6 Dynamic elaboration, para 2, b) (in part):

> Execution of a subprogram call involves the elaboration of the parameter association list. ...

Dynamic elaboration is incompatible with **open** which removes drivers that other calls to the same procedure might require.

So the rule as shown in 4.2 Subprogram declarations, 4.2.2.3 Signal parameters paragraph 6 requires the actual be a static signal name.

This particular example of a procedure is uninteresting, simply assigning elements of an array input to signal outputs.

An MCVE:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity foo is
end entity;

architecture fum of foo is   
    procedure reg2ind
     (signal reg : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
      signal e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8 : out std_logic;
      signal e9,e10,e11,e12,e13,e14,e15,e16 : out std_logic) is 
    begin
      e1 <= reg(0);
      e2 <= reg(1);      
      e3 <= reg(2);
      e4 <= reg(3);
      e5 <= reg(4);
      e6 <= reg(5);
      e7 <= reg(6);
      e8 <= reg(7);
      e9 <= reg(8);
      e10 <= reg(9);
      e11 <= reg(10);
      e12 <= reg(11);
      e13 <= reg(12);
      e14 <= reg(13);
      e15 <= reg(14);
      e16 <= reg(15);
    end procedure reg2ind;

    signal val183:  std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
    type err_record is
        record
            err_17: std_logic;
            err_18: std_logic;
            err_19: std_logic;
            err_20: std_logic;
        end record;
    type some_record is 
        record
        err: err_record;
        end record;

    signal ord_p: some_record;

    signal open5, open6, open7,
           open8, open9, open10,
           open11, open12, open13,
           open14, open15, open16:      std_logic;
begin

    reg2ind(val183,ord_p.err.err_17,ord_p.err.err_18,
    ord_p.err.err_19,ord_p.err.err_20,open5,open6,open7,open8,open5,open6,
    open7,open8,open9,open10, open11,open12);  -- with dummy outputs

    -- reg2ind(val183,ord_p.err.err_17,ord_p.err.err_18,
    -- ord_p.err.err_19,ord_p.err.err_20,open,open,open,open,open,open,
    -- open,open,open,open, open,open);  -- as presented  FAILS


end architecture;
```

The interested reader can explore the limitations of using signal based parameters.

The simplest solution might be to use an aggregate assignment target with elements re-arranged to match the actual's ordering instead of a procedure call:

```
    (ord_p.err.err_20, ord_p.err.err_19, ord_p.err.err_18, ord_p.err.err_17) <=
        val183(3 downto 0);
```

Re-arranging the target allows the right hand side to be a slice name instead of an aggregate that would also required a qualified expression. This is less textual complexity than a procedure call.

Any impetus for hiding detail by using a procedure call could be accompanied by providing a procedure with fewer parameters.

Function calls are expressions and it's not semantically possible to ignore their result value. You could enclose a statement containing a  function call or a procedure call statement in a conditionally executed statement (e.g. if statement, case statement).